# Fatal error: Call to a member function link()

Tags: opencart

i am receiving an error while editing extensions in opencart.

Fatal error: Call to a member function link() on a non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\organics2you\admin\controller\module\couponpop.php on line 28

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this problem because the different version just creat variable and pass object of url   as $data['url']=$this->url; and call it from your temp;